# Is it safe to delete local main branch?

Tags: git

Is it safe to delete the local`main` branch?

Given: My workflow does not use the local `main` branch. There are no local commits on local `main`.

I do not have any use for my local `main` branch. Does git itself depend on the existence of the `main` branch? E.g. Can a git command fail if no local `main` branch is present?

Context: I will always create a feature branch from `origin/main` and push it (optionally deleting it). I am too lazy to keep local `main` updated, but not comfortable keeping local `main` behind `origin/main`. Do you see the dilemma?! :)

Comment: "not comfortable keeping local master behind origin/master"? Why so? What do you try to avoid here?

Comment: Local changes won't affect the remote.

Comment: I really don't understand what's stopping you from `git pull`ing `master` every once in a while like a sane human being.

Comment: save or safe? Please edit the question to reflect the correct thing.

Comment: Why bother deleting it?

Comment: Deleting the name `master` won't hurt your repository, but keeping the name won't hurt your repository either (just your eyeballs, slightly :-) ). It is the *commits* that are important, and the name `origin/master` will make sure the commits themselves remain.

Comment: @Roshan Gupta Feel free to edit it. I am not native speaker and do not see why to use "save"

Comment: @MadaraUchina Laziness? I do not need to checkout master, git fetch works too;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As long as the remote `main` is still available and you are not deleting it with the local`main` branch it is no problem to do so.
But you have to be absolutely sure not to delete the remote`main` ;)